# Getting the Month and Day when the number of days are given in C#

Tags: c#

I have the count of days of the year.How can I get the specific date and month
of that date?

Eg:- Count of Days= 349   ---> This means the 14th December of a specific year

So that the 349th day is 14th December.

Help me to do this with C#

Comment: If you start with 1st of January, you need to add `348` day not `349`

Comment: Just shut your program down in leap years.

Comment: I hate it when people upvote questions just because they are easy to answer... well I say easy to answer, most the answers missed the actual requirements of getting month/year so I guess it isn't that easy after all

Comment: Ahhh among all the arguments all have given me the answers.With all of them I have solved my problem.

Thanks everybody for the answers :)

Answer (score 4):

Take January 1st and add days.

```
new DateTime(year, 1, 1).AddDays(348);
```

Comment: Note: 348 came from 349 - 1, imagine the first day of a year is 1st Jan, it should add 0 day (1 - 1)

Comment: Yes, 348 because January 1st is day nr 1. But I realized I switched around the parameters. The year should come first. Edited.

Comment: @musefan Because helping is the spirit of SO.. (buzz lightyear) look, similar answers everywhere

Answer (score 1):

according to my calculations it's the 15th of december

```
int iCount = 349;
DateTime dtResult = new DateTime(2015, 1, 1).AddDays(iCount - 1);
int Month = dtResult.Month;
int Day = dtResult.Day;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(2015,1, 1).AddDays(348);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 DateTime date = new DateTime(2014,12,31).AddDays(349);
```

If you start on the first day of the year and add days you'll be one day out!

Comment: Why the downvote? the answer is correct, and what's more it explains why you shouldn't start on the first day of the year (or subtract 1 day).